# Game Simulation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

im kinda new in java and im doing an multithtreading resource-game where i have 3 classes.

- > Playground class (where resources are held ...gold,wood,food)
- > Animat class (where i have animats that use the resources when i want to)
- > Game(Main) class (to run the game)

Can anyone tell me how can i use a thread so i can make an Animat reduce Resources from the playground class? 
...Actually i want to know if i can make threads to run methods and how...

Comment: You want to know if threads can run methods? I think you need to read a few good books or tutorials on Java before writing a multithreaded program. Try [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for starters.

Comment: This is too open-ended. You should try writing/running a `Thread` in java. From there on, things will be much clearer to you.

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Closed as not a real question because I didn't use CAPS? Some people here have issues...

Comment: @user2375278 No its closed as its not a real question. Theres not enough detail here to even start to answer your question. Someone has given you some help on threads in general and thats all you were ever going to achieve from this question. Also "im kinda new in java and im doing an multithtreading", I'm kindof experienced in java and I still treat threads with the respect they deserve; they are an advanced topic, can easily cause bugs for the unwary and your game is very unlikely to need them. (Not that you can't try, i'm just warning you that they're not for the faint hearted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Thread type**

A thread is another execution call, that runs in parallel to the thread that called it. Every Java program starts out with the `main` thread. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is the documentation.

**Writing a class to use the Thread type**

When you write your class, you can attach the keyword `extends` to the header, along with the class name. In this case, `Thread`.

```
public class A extends Thread
```

At this point, you'll be asked to implement a method, `run`. This is the loop that will be executed for the lifetime of the thread.

```
public void run()
{
    // Some code.
}
```

**In your case**

You want to use resources from another class, so it might be wise to pass in a reference to this other class, via `A`'s constructor.

```
public A(Playground playground)
{
    this.playground = playground;
    // Assumes a field of type Playground called playground.
}
```

In your run method, you'll want to be decrementing some values. This is nice and simple.

```
public void run()
{
    while(gameIsNotOver)
    {
        // Loop assumes some boolean value, gameIsNotOver.
        playground.methodCall();
        // Call some method that will perform the requested calculations on the values.
    }
}
```

**Using the thread**

In your main class, when you want to start this thread, do **NOT** call the `run` method. This will not start an asynchronous execution. You should call the `start` method. This will start the thread, and it will begin decrementing values.